# Loop to check for the tag of a button

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, loops

I am new to ObjC. I have a method in my controller class called

```
-(IBAction)playSound:(id)sender;
```

If I wanted to fill out the method by writing a `for` loop that checks the tag of each of my four buttons (already linked in storyboard), how would I do that? I am trying to make a button click play a sound. Please be descriptive in your answer.

Comment: are you trying to determine the tag of the button that was pressed? You can just use `((UIButton*)sender).tag`

Comment: If you want a button click to play a sound, just make an array/dictionary to match your buttons

Comment: Why would you use a `for` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)playSound:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender; // this is the button that has been pressed
    if (button.tag == 0) {
        // Play song for button 0
    } else if (button.tag == 1) {
        // Play song for button 1
    }   // ...
}
```

Or

```
-(IBAction)playSound:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender; // this is the button that has been pressed
    NSString *songName = [songs objectAtIndex:button.tag]; // songs is an array
    // Play song
}
```